# Como se lê a radiciação de um número com índice diferente de 2 (raiz quadrada de) e 3 (raiz cúbica de)?

Tags: português-europeu

A [radiciação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radicia%C3%A7%C3%A3o) é a operação matemática inversa à potenciação.

“√1” lê-se “raiz quadrada de um”, e “∛1” lê-se “raiz cúbica de um”.

Como é que se lê as raízes com outros índices, utilizando os [numerais multiplicativos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_(lingu%C3%ADstica)#Numerais_multiplicativos)?

Por exemplo, com índice 4 (“∜1”) lê-se “raiz quádrupla de um” e com índice 5 lê-se “raiz quíntupla de um”?

E se o índice for negativo, ou uma fração?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em Português Europeu diz-se: *"a [enésima](https://dicionario.priberam.org/en%C3%A9sima) raiz de"*. (Dito de modo análogo ao [*"nth root"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root) do Inglês.)

Se reparares, [*"radiciação"*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/radicia%C3%A7%C3%A3o) é substantivo feminino. O vocábulo não existe enquanto verbo para poder descrever uma acção.

Para descrever, por exemplo:

- <sup>4</sup>√15<sup>2</sup> diz-se:"raiz índice 4 do quadrado de quinze".
- <sup>14</sup>√5<sup>12</sup> diz-se: "raiz índice quatorze de cinco levantado a doze."

Também se pode dizer por via da exponenciação:

- 15 <sup>2/4</sup> quinze levantado a dois quartos.
- 15 <sup>12/14</sup> quinze levantado a doze sobre quatorze (ou, doze quatorze avos).

Ou em termos de "a potência":

- 15 <sup>- 12/14</sup> quinze levantado à potência negativa de doze sobre quatorze.

(Já se passaram muitos anos desde que andei nas aulas de matemática, pode haver alguma falta de preciosismo no que escrevi, mas no essencial é isto.)

Comment: Em pt-BR não se diz "levantado à potência", mas sim "**elevado** à potência".

Comment: É complicado dizer se a resposta está correta, ou até se há uma só resposta correta. Estranho que aparentemente ninguém no passado perguntou isto o suficiente para haver a informação disponível fácil de se encontrar. A minha questão era mais haver com exemplos como: `⁻⁽¹/³⁾√10²`. As potências eu sei.

Comment: @user7393973 o teu exemplo `⁻⁽¹/³⁾√10²` simplificado é 10^-6 fica 0.000001 é um "micro". Primeiro simplificas, depois dizes "por extenso" o resultado simplificado.

Answer (score 2):

Em geral [se diz](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raiz_da_unidade):

> raiz n-ésima

ou seja, usam-se os numerais ordinais:

- <sup>4</sup>√x = x<sup>1/4</sup> : raiz quarta
- <sup>5</sup>√x = x<sup>1/5</sup> : raiz quinta
- ...

Os consagrados termos "raiz quadrada" e "raiz cúbica" possivelmente se originam das formas geométricas "quadrado" e "cubo", não dos numerais multiplicativos.

Analogamente, também se lê x<sup>n</sup> como "x (elevado) à n-ésima potência" ou simplesmente "x (elevado) a n".

Comment: O verbete linkado da Wikipedia contém um exemplo explícito do uso: "*i* é uma raiz quarta e raiz oitava da unidade, mas é apenas uma raiz quarta primitiva da unidade." 
Outro exemplo do uso se encontra na página https://alunosonline.uol.com.br/matematica/radiciacao.html : "Nesse exemplo, temos uma raiz quarta".