# Qual a origem da expressão “raiz quadrada” e “(elevado) ao quadrado”?

Tags: expressões, origem

Quando falamos de um número *elevado ao quadrado*, falamos desse número multiplicado por si (3 ao quadrado é 3x3), e quando falamos da raiz quadrada de um número, falamos do número que ao quadrado é igual àquele, primeiro, número (a raiz quadrada de 9 é 3 porque 3x3 = 9).

Mas por que dizemos *(elevado) ao quadrado* e *raiz quadrada*? Isto é, inclusive, semelhante ao inglês, *square root* e *squared*. Se condisser, por que falamos *(elevado) ao cubo* e *raiz cúbica*?

Comment: Se eu não me engano, antigamente se pensava mais na geometria, então, elevar um número ao quadrado seria como se o elevássemos do mundo 1D (de reta, linha, medida) para o mundo 2D (para quadrado); e tirar a raiz quadrada dum número seria tirar o número de origem (daí, *raiz*) dum quadrado com essa área. Eu acho que é algo do gênero.

Comment: Related: [Como se lê a radiciação de um número com índice diferente de 2 (raiz quadrada de) e 3 (raiz cúbica de)?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/7802/2764).

Comment: Eu vi alguns sites dizerem que é porque um número ao quadrado é a área dum quadrado cujos lados medem esse número, mas isto é porque medimos com quadrados, como metros quadrados.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu encontrei a papinha praticamente toda feita neste [Why the name “square root”? no SE Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/809799/why-the-name-square-root#:%7E:text=The%20idea%20of%20the%20square,it%20was%20its%20square%20root.).

Estes termos matemáticos vieram-nos do latim, e no latim a inspiração deste *quadrado* veio da geometria. Tanto, que também se usou *latus* (’lado’) em vez de *radix* (’raiz’)! Aliás, *radix* era só raiz de planta, e só adquiriu o sentido matemático quando foi usado para traduzir o árabe *jadhr*. Cito [Solomon Gandz (“On the origin of the term ‘root,’” *The American Mathematical Monthly*, 1926](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2299558.pdf); minha tradução):

> “Obras Latinas traduzidas do árabe têm *radix* como termo comum, enquanto as herdadas da civilização romana têm *latus*.” [Smith, *History of Mathematics*] *Radix* (“raiz”) é o árabe *jadhr*, enquanto *latus* [...] é o lado do quadrado geométrico.

O matemático português [Pedro Nunes, (*Libro de Algebra en Arithmetica y Geometria*, 1567)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=EU3zLI18WXUC&pg=PA54&lpg=PA54&dq=%22lados%20quadrados%20o%20raizes%22&source=bl&ots=OXaxuobB93&sig=ACfU3U0IdIa01cWtWjApsfVdZVbZ0zsHHg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwit5_Xrjs72AhXwiP0HHUZLAQUQ6AF6BAgDEAM#v=onepage&q=%22lados%20quadrados%20o%20raizes%22&f=false) também usou *lado quadrado* (ele escreveu isto em espanhol; no link têm a figura; negrito meu):

> Sean las dos lineas a.b y b.c **lados quadrados o raizes** de dos numeros conocidos, las quales lineas juntas consituyen la linea a.c que de entrambas es compuesta. Y queremos por la dicha Regla saber de que quantidad essa linea a.c es **lado quadrado, a que al presente llamamos raiz**.

Agora, porquê o latim ***radix***? [Solomon Gandz](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2299558.pdf) argumenta que os doutores medievais europeus traduziram mal o árabe *jadhr*. É verdade que este termo significava ’raiz’ no sentido botânico; mas significava também ’base’ e ’fundação’, que segundo ele seriam os significados relevantes no sentido matemático.

Isto já se afasta muito da língua portuguesa, e eu não sei se compreendi bem o pensamento dos matemáticos árabes medievais, mas ao que me pareceu, eles concebiam a área dum quadrado (ou retângulo) como o produto de um lado por uma unidade quadrada, produto este que constituiria o tal *jadhr* ou base quadrada, multiplicado pelo outro lado. Eu imagino isto assim. Suponhamos que a nossa unidade quadrada é um metro quadrado, e que queremos medir um terreno quadrado. Eu imagino o *jadhr* ou base quadrada como uma tira de um metro de largura ao longo de um dos lados do terreno, que seria depois multipicads pelo comprimento do outro lado. Solomon Gandz num artigo posterior ([“On the origin of the term ‘root.’ Second article,” *The American Mathematical Monthly*, 1928](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2299460)), explica que isto poderá ser uma reminiscência da prática egípcia já em 1600 AC, que usavam como unidade básica de medida de terrenos tiras de um por cem cúbitos.

Comment: Bah, me bateu nessa — eu estava elaborando uma resposta baseada nas mesmas fontes (e também no [English SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/520491/where-does-the-mathematical-use-of-the-word-root-come-from/520699#520699)).

Comment: @stafusa, olha ainda bem que não fiquei mais oito dias à procura de fontes antigas. Agora, tu que és cientista, parece que para o [Pedro Nunes (1567)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=EU3zLI18WXUC&pg=PA44&lpg=PA44&dq=%22este+lado+quadrado%22&source=bl&ots=OXaxwkaxbZ&sig=ACfU3U0Nvj6hloAIH85U9B26yOSm6Sf1YQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjvkOjc3dL2AhVjSvEDHXXbDWEQ6AF6BAgSEAM#v=onepage&q=%22este%20lado%20quadrado%22&f=false) raízes são só os inteiros; os irracionais seriam apenas "lados quadrados" e só impropriamente se lhes chamavam raízes. Não atinei foi com o método geométrico dele de os identificar.

Comment: Os números irracionais levaram muito tempo para serem aceitos como números de fato (os racionais também - para muitos só os naturais [=inteiros positivos] eram aceitáveis) e foi justamente por volta do século XVI que esse processo começou a ganhar força (https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/3213/10299), então o texto do Pedro Nunes diferencia entre raízes inteiras e as (consideradas inferiores, embora úteis) irracionais. Sobre os proporções (um número _b_ entre _a_ e _c_ tal que _a/b_ é igual a _b/c_) também não sei qual é a motivação, imagino que só fique claro em outras partes do livro.

Comment: Desculpa pela demora Jacinto. E muito obrigado pela resposta.